# Azure Storage SDK Upgrade for .Net 3.5

Tags: c#, .net, azure, .net-3.5, azure-blob-storage

I'm maintaining a legacy product that is deployed to SharePoint 2010, and targets .Net framework 3.5. It uses the Azure SDK 1.7 for blob operations and with the SDK getting deprecated soon, we need to upgrade it. According to [this blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazurestorage/archive/2014/08/05/microsoft-azure-storage-service-version-removal.aspx) the minimum SDK version should be 2.1, but the issue is that the it does not support .net 3.5.

I looked at the SDK code on [GitHub](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-net) and it's highly dependent on .Net 4 features so I cannot recompile it in .net 3.5. I looked for 3rd party SDKs but couldn't find any.

Is there a straightforward way to keep the functionality after Azure Storage service version removal?

(Please note that upgrading the .Net framework is not an option for me.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, unfortunately our client library support is only for .NET 4.0 (2010) and later.

If you need to maintain support for the legacy project, you'll need to decide between writing your own REST calls to Azure Storage or upgrading your .NET framework to 4.0 to use a newer version of the library. Sorry!

Comment: Thanks Peter. I think the SharePoint 2010 will not be upgraded to support .NET framework 4.0. Right?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who might have the same problem:

The deprecation of Storage client library 1.7 is postponed beyond August 2016.

[Microsoft Azure Storage Service Version Removal Update: Extension to 2016](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazurestorage/archive/2015/10/19/microsoft-azure-storage-service-version-removal-update-extension-to-2016.aspx)